# How to call a JS function with the new js (0.6.0) package

Tags: dart, dart-js-interop

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var testFunction = function() {return 'xxx'};
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.dart**

```
import 'dart:js' as js;
import 'package:js/js.dart';

@Js() // about to being changed to @JS
external String testFunction();

main() {
  // fails: Exception: Uncaught Error: No top-level method 'testFunction' declared.
  print(testFunction()); 

  // works
  print((js.context['testFunction'] as js.JsFunction).apply([]));
}
```

> Dart VM version: 1.13.0-edge.a598fea28cf26ed82b0a197e65af33a7edca5cac (Thu Oct 15 18:02:15 2015) on "linux_x64"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works as expected.

I just had Dartium running during the Dart update and had still the old version running when I tried the example. After closing and reopening Dartium the code worked fine.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: Actually it is a complete answer. The code in the question works fine, the browser version was too old to support features used in the code. I considered closing the question but decided against it because I think it might serve others. I updated my answer.